# Derivation of the retarded Green function: Problem with a Cauchy integral

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, cauchy-integral-formula, greens-function

I'm currently following a derivation of the retarded Greens function in my Electrodynamics course.

We arrived at a integral of the following form: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mathrm d\omega\frac{1}{c^2k^2-\omega^2}e^{-i\omega\tau}$$

with poles at $\omega=\pm ck$.

The poles are located on the real-axis and we choose an integration path such that the two poles are by-passed in the upper half-plane.

Now my book says that if we have $\tau>0$ we have to close our integration path on the lower half-plane and if $\tau<0$ we have to close it in the upper half-plane so that the exponential doesn't blow up at infinity.

I don't really get why. Because if we have $\tau>0$, the exponent stays negtive so the imaginary part of $\omega$ would need to go to $+\infty$ for $e^{-i\omega\tau}$ to not blow up. So we would need to close our half circle in the upper half-plane. The same reasoning applies for the case $\tau<0$.

It would be great if someone could point out my mistake here. Appreciate any advice, thanks!

Comment: Ok I think I found my problem: If I parametrize my $\omega$ as $\omega=Re^{i\Theta}$ I can write my exponential as $$e^{-i\tau Rcos(\Theta)}e^{\tau Rsin(\Theta)}$$ and if I now let $\tau>0$ and $R\to\infty$, I get the condition to close my integration on the lower half-plane such that $sin(\Theta)<0$

Comment: Maybe you want to self answer it. [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%27s_lemma) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma) should be interesting.

Comment: And for your future sanity keep in mind the original integral doesn't exist in the usual sense as it stands, you're calculating a principal value.